# AJAX JQuery PHP mail sending form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, email

I am working on a site which having 2 contact forms, and I use ajax jquery to send mail via php.

When I use single form and jQuery, it works fine.
And when I paste the jQuery code and modify as per form 2 variables, it works, but then first jQuery code is sending blank values.
Over all at a time, only 1 form is working for my HTML forms on different page.

I appreciate your help in advance.
Jquery code

```
var form=$('#contactform_forms');
var formMessages=$('#message');

$(form).submit(function(e){
  $('#submit_btns')
    .after('<img src="images/AjaxLoader.gif" class="loader" />')
    .attr('disabled','disabled');
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData=$(form).serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'contact.php',
    data:formData
  })
    .done(function(response){
    $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
    $(formMessages).addClass('success');
    $(formMessages).text('Thanks! Message has been sent.');
    $(formMessages).fadeOut(10000);
    $('#contactform_forms img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
    $('#submit_btns').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#contact_name').val('');
    $('#contact_email').val('');
    $('#contact_phone').val('');
    $('#contact_message').val('');

  }).fail(function(data){
    $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
    $(formMessages).addClass('error');
    if(data.responseText!==''){
      $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
    }else{
      $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured.');
    }
  });
});
```

jQuery code for form 2 with the same js file:

```
var form=$('#wholesalers_forms');
var formMessages=$('#message');

$(form).submit(function(e){
  $('#submit_btns1')
    .after('<img src="images/AjaxLoader.gif" class="loader" />')
    .attr('disabled','disabled');
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData=$(form).serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'wholesalers.php',
    data:formData
  })
    .done(function(response){
    $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
    $(formMessages).addClass('success');
    $(formMessages).text('Thanks! Message has been sent.');
    $(formMessages).fadeOut(10000);
    $('#wholesalers_forms img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
    $('#submit_btns1').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#hs_name').val('');
    $('#hs_email').val('');
    $('#hs_company').val('');
    $('#hs_vat').val('');
    $('#hs_address').val('');
    $('#hs_postcode').val('');
    $('#hs_city').val('');
    $('#hs_phone').val('');
    $('#hs_message').val('');

  }).fail(function(data){
    $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
    $(formMessages).addClass('error');
    if(data.responseText!==''){
      $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
    }else{
      $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured.');
    }
  });
});
```

When I use both as the above order: 1st one send empty value and second form working perfectly, if i remove 2nd jQuery then first code working fine, but second do not have code to send.

Comment: can you please paste the general code including HTML with both the forms and related js?

Comment: You shouldn't just copy paste the jQuery code a second time. You need to rewrite the function so it'll work for both forms, then call it appropriately depending on which submit button was clicked.

Comment: Yes Chris, i rewrite that, i have posted both code, but it is not working for me.

Comment: I think those 2 scripts are ON THE SAME page. Therefore, the 2 `var` and the `.submit()` handler are overwritten. (it fits the problem description...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here. First I can see you've got duplicate element IDs on the page which will produce undefined results. Second, you shouldn't be copying and pasting code but iterating through (or making generic) your code, depending on the usage. This keeps your code DRY. Further reading here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself.

If you are still having trouble, add a jsFiddle with the specific parts of the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: Which element IDs is duplicate i couldn't find due to limited knowledge in jQuery.

Comment: This is related to the HTML standards and the DOM, not specifically jQuery. You will need to post your example HTML too, preferably in some editable container (jsFiddle, js bin, etc.). Specifically it looks like you have more than one element with the same ID of `message`.

Comment: Now it working after replacing all (duplicate or same name variable) in both code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
function getFormData(form_id) { 
    var form_data = {};
    $.each($("#" + form_id).serializeArray(), function(i, obj) {
        if (form_data[obj.name] == undefined) {
            form_data[obj.name] = obj.value;
        } else if (typeof form_data[obj.name] == Array) {
            form_data[obj.name].push(obj.value);
        } else {
            form_data[obj.name] = [form_data[obj.name], obj.value];
        }
    });
    return form_data;
}

function validate(form_id) {
    var error = false;

    //run some validation, which alters display and sets error to true on failure.

    return error;
}

$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event) {
    var form_id = $(this).attr("id");
    if (validate(form_id)) { //If error is found.
        event.preventDefault();
    } else { //Else the form is good.
        var form_data = getFormData(form_id),
            url = (form_id == "contactform_forms") ? "contact.php" : "wholsalers.php";
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: url,
            data: form_data,
            success: function(data) {
                //Display a confirmation message.
            }
        })
    }
});
```